# SUMIF Down Rows & Accross Columns

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

SUMIF Down Rows & Accross Columns Help

I've successfully been able to use SUMIF to match a list down a column but lack the knowledge to run it across the columns without setting each of the column headers individually.  Appreciate any feedback from the brilliant StackOverflow mind pool.

```
Sub SUMIF_Down_Rows_Across_Columns()


    'Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    'Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    
    'Set ws1 = Sheets("Not_Split")
    'Set ws2 = Sheets("PNL_Large")
    
    Dim lrow1 As Long, lrow2 As Long ' first lrow controls the database, the second lrow is for the reference list column
    
    lrow1 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lrow2 = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rng1 As Range ' reference list
    Set rng1 = Range("k1")
    
    
    stJan = [l2] 'start & end dates
    endJan = [l3]
    
    stFEB = [m2] 'start & end dates
    EndFEB = [m3]
    
    stMAR = [n2] 'start & end dates
    EndMAR = [n3]
    
    stAPR = [o2] 'start & end dates
    EndAPR = [o3]
    
    stMAY = [p2] 'start & end dates
    EndMAY = [p3]
    
    stJUN = [q2] 'start & end dates
    EndJUN = [q3]
    
    stJUL = [r2] 'start & end dates
    EndJUL = [r3]
    
    Dim Dates As Range, Categories As Range, Debits As Range, Credits As Range
    
    Set Dates = Sheet6.Range("B2:B" & lrow1)
    Set Categories = Sheet6.Range("C2:C" & lrow1)
    Set Debits = Sheet6.Range("D2:D" & lrow1)
    
    ' JAN ===============================================================
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    JANtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stJan, Dates, "<=" & endJan, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 12) = JANtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' FEB ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    FEBtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stFEB, Dates, "<=" & EndFEB, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 13) = FEBtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' MAR ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    MARtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stMAR, Dates, "<=" & EndMAR, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 14) = MARtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' APR ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    APRtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stAPR, Dates, "<=" & EndAPR, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 15) = APRtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' MAY ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    MAYtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stMAY, Dates, "<=" & EndMAY, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 16) = MAYtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' JUN ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    JUNtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stJUN, Dates, "<=" & EndJUN, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 17) = JUNtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' JUL ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    JULtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stJUL, Dates, "<=" & EndJUL, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 18) = JULtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' AUG ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    AUGtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stAUG, Dates, "<=" & EndAUG, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 19) = AUGtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' SEP ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    SEPtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stSEP, Dates, "<=" & EndSEP, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 20) = SEPtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' OCT ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    OCTtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stOCT, Dates, "<=" & EndOCT, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 21) = OCTtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' NOV ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    NOVtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stNOV, Dates, "<=" & EndNOV, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 22) = NOVtotals
    
    Next I
    
    ' DEC ===============================================================
    
    For I = 9 To lrow2
    
    DECtotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, ">=" & stDEC, Dates, "<=" & EndDEC, Categories, Cells(I, 11))
    
    Cells(I, 23) = DECtotals
    
    Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too long for a review here. It needn't be that. The code below should do much the same thing. Note that I tested it without data only.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    ' 061
    
    Const Yr        As Integer = 2020
    Dim M           As Integer              ' loop counter: month
    
    For M = 1 To 12
        WriteMonthTotals M, Yr
    Next M
End Sub

Private Sub WriteMonthTotals(ByVal Mnth As Integer, _
                             ByVal Yr As Integer)
    ' 061
    
    Dim DateRng     As Range
    Dim CatRng      As Range
    Dim DrRng       As Range
    Dim StartDate   As Date         ' first day of Mnth
    Dim EndDate     As Date         ' last day of Mnth
    Dim Tmp         As Double       ' sum
    Dim C           As Long         ' target column
    Dim R           As Long         ' loop counter: Row
    
    StartDate = DateSerial(Yr, Mnth, 1)
    EndDate = DateSerial(Yr, Mnth + 1, 0)
    Debug.Print StartDate, EndDate
    C = 11 + Mnth
    
    With Sheet6
        Set DateRng = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        Set CatRng = DateRng.Offset(, 1)
        Set DrRng = DateRng.Offset(, 2)
        
        For R = 9 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
            Tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(DrRng, _
                                                       DateRng, ">=" & StartDate, _
                                                       DateRng, "<=" & EndDate, _
                                                       CatRng, .Cells(R, 11).Value)
            .Cells(R, C) = Tmp
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

The key difference is in the code structure. The *Main* procedure calls the sub-procedure 12 times, once for each month. That procedure remains identical, of course. Just the output is shifted to adjacent, consecutive columns and Excel is very good at calculating the beginnings and ends of months once you tell it which month you have in mind.

In your code you referred to `Sheet6` at times and the `ActiveSheet` (by default, due to omission) most of the time. I concentrated the action on `Sheet6`.

Having reduced the code to a size that fits one page I wasn't able to find out which columns you were referring to in your question. Perhaps you will be able to find a solution yourself once you familiarize yourself with the new structure and its capabilities. If not, please do feel free to use the new code as the base for a better explanation of what you still need to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you Variatus, i've tried running the code after i ensured all the columns and everything was lined up with your code but when i try to run it, it opens the macro picker. I am assuming it has something to do with the code you put inside the Sub ( ...) ?  Appreciate the feedback once again.

Comment: You may have placed the cursor in the procedure `WriteMonthTotal` and pressed F5. That procedure can't be run with F5. It's designed for use by `Main`. Place the cursor in the `Main` procedure. That procedure is also listed in the Macro Picker and you could run it from there.

Comment: Thank you Variatus, it took me some fooling about to figure it out but it works BEAUTIFULLY thank you so much... AWESOMENESS!  Now i'll have to learn the code.  Thanks AGAIN!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback. Please remember to mark my answer as *Selected*. I'm angling for the 10K reputation before Independence Day lol:

Comment: Absolutely, ill just need to google how to mark you as Selected (sorry newbie).  Once last questions cuz your live at the moment.  If i wanted to run the sumif match from a different sheet than sheet6 (say i have the table on sheet5 and the data on sheet6) how would change the code?

Comment: `With Sheet6` is a sort-of shorthand. Between its declaration and `End With` every leading period creates an implied reference to `Sheet6`. Meaning every leading period could be replaced with a hard reference, e.g. ` Set DateRng = Sheet6.Range(Sheet6.Cells(2, "B"), sheet6.Cells(sheet6.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))`. So, you could re-direct individual items to another sheet even within the With Sheet6 block. But I think you could close the Sheet6 block once the ranges are set and start a `With Sheet5` block before the for .. Next loop.

Comment: Thank you again.  On a separate note. is there anyway to set [As Integer = 2020] in Main to a cell in a worksheet (so i can simply import the year data into different sheets without modifying the Integer each time)?  Next step is to turn these workbooks into a database with web interface. Do you work as a Excel programming freelancer by any chance?  I've been using Upwork since inception (elance) and am interested in talking to you (or someone you know) about outsourcing the project if any interests (hope i am not breaking any SO rules or guidelines by inquiring of such.  Cheers